# Database deadlock during Spring JUnit with before-after sql

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, junit, deadlock

In my SpringBoot application, I have a simple test case, where I want this:
insert some data into database before the test
do some validation in the test
delete the data from the database after the test
This is how I wrote it:

The interface which holds the sql-s.

```
@Target(METHOD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Sql(scripts = "/insert-data-before.sql", config = @SqlConfig(transactionMode = ISOLATED), executionPhase = BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
@Sql(scripts = "/delete-data-after.sql", config = @SqlConfig(transactionMode = ISOLATED), executionPhase = AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
public @interface PrepareAndRollbackDataForTesting {
}
```

The test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server")
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyTestApplication.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Transactional
public abstract class MyTestClass {
    @Test
    @PrepareAndRollbackDataForTesting
    public void testTheData() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

insert-data-before.sql:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO mytable(id, name) VALUES (1, 'test');
COMMIT;
```

delete-data-after.sql:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM mytable;
COMMIT;
```

But if I write this way, it will end up in a **deadlock**.

If I delete the delete-data-after.sql @Sql from the interface, it works fine!

Also if I delete the config from the @Sql-s from the interface, it works fine!

But I want to run the insert and delete sql in a separate transaction, to be sure that it will delete all data no matter what happens inside the method, even in case of exception!

Comment: What database you are using for your tests? Most of embedded databases don't support multiple transactions.

Comment: Post here your table structure + deadlock graph

Comment: Thanks guys, but I have t he answer finally!

Answer (score 0):

I have found out!

I just have to delete the config from the interface:

```
@Target(METHOD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Sql(scripts = "/insert-data-before.sql", executionPhase = BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
@Sql(scripts = "/delete-data-after.sql", executionPhase = AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
public @interface PrepareAndRollbackDataForTesting {
}
```

Because the `@Transactional` annotation will take care of the transaction, and will rollback afterwards.

**EDIT:**

Also I deleted the BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT thingy from the sqls.

Comment: Or don't start transactions yourself. The config you had already started a new transaction for the script to commit it afterwards. As you started another tx you had a deadlock on that.

Comment: oh yes, I forgot to mention that I deleted the BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT thingy from the sqls